# Fragment inside ViewPager doesn't scroll

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an `Activity` that have an `appBarLayout` with a `TabLayout` that should cover the  2/5 of the screen, so it's a big `AppBarLayout`. I created it, made the tabLayout and configured the `viewPager` and it is working, but there are three with issues that I can't figure out how to resolve:

1. Without this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` the viewpager shows beside the `appBarLayout`
2. Whenever I enter in any of the editTexts the AppBarLayout shows fullscreen.
3. The second fragment has big height and should scroll down, but the it doesn't.

**Relevant code:**

Activity with the `appBarLayout` and the `viewPager`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/green_900"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_home"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_version"
            android:text="@string/app_version"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/light_green_a700"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white_background" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The second page (Tab) that should scroll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="23dp"
        android:background="@color/white_background">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_facebook_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/facebook_register"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb_logo"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/button_facebook_shape"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/white_line"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"/>
        <View
            android:background="@color/login_hint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/white_line"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/login_hint"
            android:background="@color/white_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="o con tu mail..."/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_register_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:textColorHint="@color/login_hint"
        android:hint="@string/txt_register_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_register_lastname"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="@color/login_hint"
        android:hint="@string/txt_register_last_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_register_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="@color/login_hint"
        android:hint="@string/txt_register_email"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_register_pass"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="@color/login_hint"
        android:hint="@string/txt_register_pass"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_register_pss_conf"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorHint="@color/login_hint"
        android:hint="@string/txt_register_pass_confirm"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_register_done"
            android:text="@string/btn_register_done"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/kick"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_done_shape"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The java code for the `Activity` and the `viewPager`

```
public class LoginRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new myFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), LoginRegisterActivity.this));

        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public class myFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
        private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"Ingresar", "Registrarse"};
        private Context context;

        public myFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return LoginFragment.newInstance(position);
                case 1:
                    return RegisterFragment.newInstance(position);
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Generate title based on item position
            return tabTitles[position];
        }
    }
```